# Swap Normal Mode Mappings of two letters in Vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I use Turkish-F keyboard layout where the key <kbd>w</kbd> is very far from home row. In order to prevent carpal tunnel in my right baby finger, I want to swap the normal mode mappings of `e` and `w`.

I can do it using the following mappings:

```
nnoremap w e
nnoremap e w
```

But this doesn't swap `e` and `w` when they are used in combination with other mappings such as `diw` or `die`.

How can I swap all mappings involving `e` with `w` and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

After mapping

```
nnoremap w e
nnoremap e w
```

If you look at the output of `:map`, you can see

```
e         * w
w         * e
```

Motions like `iw`, `aw` will not respect this mapping as they are a different motion (text object) altogether.

One workaround is to add extra mappings like

```
onoremap ie iw
onoremap ae aw
```

Also note that operators like `c`, `d`, `y` takes you to [operator-pending mode](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/15.html), hence `onoremap`

Comment: How about for example `d2e`. I tried the following, but it doesn't do the mapping properly: 
`nnoremap de dw`
`nnoremap dw de`

Comment: If you have `nnoremap w e` and `nnoremap e w` , `d2e` should work. My solution was to add extra mappings for other text objects.